# How do Arguments and Parameters Work in Python?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, parameters, arguments

I have looked all over Stackoverflow and I can't find an answer, and all the web tutorials just go right over my head. I have a functioning code that I don't understand

```
import random
import time

def displayIntro():
    print('You are in a land full of dragons. In front of you,')
    print('you see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with you. The other dragon')
    print('is greedy nd hungry, and will eat you on sight.')
    print()

def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave != '1' and cave != '2':
        print('Which cave will you go into? (1 or 2)')
        cave = input()

    return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('A large dragon jumps out in front of you! He opens his jaws and...')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    friendlyCave = random.randint(1, 2)

    if chosenCave == str(friendlyCave):
        print('Gives you his treasure')
    else:
        print('Gobbles you down in one bite!')

playAgain = 'yes'
while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':
    displayIntro()
    caveNumber = chooseCave()
    checkCave(caveNumber)
    print('do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
```

I don't understand the `def checkCave(chosenCave):` parts, why does the argument say `chosenCave`?
Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function

```
def checkCave(chosenCave):
    ...
```

`chosenCave` becomes a local variable that you passed to the function. You can then access the value inside that function to process it, provide whatever side-effects you're looking to provide (like printing to the screen, as you're doing), and then return a value, (which if you don't do explicitly, Python returns `None`, its null value, by default.)

### Algebraic Analogy

In algebra we define functions like this:

```
f(x) = ...
```

for example:

```
f(x) = x*x
```

In Python we define functions like this:

```
def f(x):
    ...
```

and in keeping with the above simple example:

```
def f(x):
    return x*x
```

When we want the results of that function applied to a particular x, (e.g., 1), we call it, and it returns the result after processing that particular x.:

```
particular_x = 1    
f(particular_x)
```

And if it returns a result we want for later usage, we can assign the results of calling that function to a variable:

```
y = f(particular_x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The name `chosenCave` appears to have been chosen to describe what it represents, namely, the cave the player chose. Were you expecting it to be named something else? The name isn't required to match or not match any names located elsewhere in the program.